# Solve function for real part = 0 instead of imaginary in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, mathematical-optimization, eigenvalue

I have a function which outputs a vector of complex eigenvalues. It takes a single argument, `rho`.  I need to find a `rho` for which the complex eigenvalues lie on the imaginary axis. In other words, the real parts have to be 0.

When I run `fzero()` it throws the following error

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Whereas `fsolve()` simply solves for the imaginary part = 0, which is exactly the oposite of what I want.

This is the function I wrote

```
function lambda = eigLorenz(rho)
beta = 8/3;
sigma = 10;
eta = sqrt(beta*(rho-1));
A = [ -beta 0 eta;0 -sigma sigma;-eta rho -1];
y = [rho-1; eta; eta];

% Calculate eigenvalues of jacobian
J = A + [0 y(3) 0; 0 0 0; 0 -y(1) 0]

lambda = eig(J)
```

It outputs 3 eigenvalues, 2 complex conjugates and 1 real eigenvalue (with complex part = 0).
I need to find `rho` for which the complex eigenvalues lie on the imaginary axis so that the real parts are 0.

Comment: What's the valid range of ρ? Because just filling in some random values does not give the 1-real-and-2-conjugates that you describe...is this actually a requirement?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis A valid range is rho > 0. The solution is rho = 24.737, but now I need a way to get that to work in MATLAB

Comment: The 2 conjugates + real value only start happening for ρ > 1.34561...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. `fzero` is only suited for scalar-valued functions (f: ℝ → ℝ)
2. complex numbers are single numbers, treated as signle entities by almost all functions. You'll have to force MATLAB to split up the complex number into its imaginary and real parts

So, one possible workaround is to take the real part of the first complex eigenvalue:

```
function [output, lambda] = eigLorenz(rho)

    % Constants
    beta  = 8/3;
    sigma = 10;

    eta = sqrt(beta*(rho-1));
    A = [-beta        0     eta
             0   -sigma   sigma
          -eta      rho      -1];

    y = [rho-1
         eta
         eta];

    % Calculate eigenvalues of jacobian
    J = A + [0 y(3)  0
             0    0  0
             0 -y(1) 0];

    lambda = eig(J);

    % Make it all work for all rho with FZERO(). Check whether:
    % - the complex eigenvalues are indeed each other's conjugates   
    % - there are exactly 2 eigenvalues with nonzero imaginary part
    complex = lambda(imag(lambda) ~= 0);
    if numel(complex) == 2 && ...
            ( abs(complex(1) - conj(complex(2))) < sqrt(eps) )

        output = real(complex(1));   

    else
        % Help FZERO() get out of this hopeless valley
        output = -norm(lambda);
    end

end
```

Call like this:

```
rho = fzero(@eigLorenz, 0);
[~, lambda] = eigLorenz(rho);
```

Comment: I was just about to comment that you need to get `lambda(1)` but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: ...yes but it's not very robust; this only works as long as ρ > 1.34561...I'm still not happy! There will be a few more edits :)

Comment: This is a fantastic solution!